# How to create an autoreversing animation that loops forever in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm trying to do a simple automatically reversing animation.

```
SKAction *a = [SKAction moveToX:10 duration:0.5];
a = [SKAction repeatActionForever:a];
[car runAction:a];
```

But the action doesn't reverse. How do you get a similar autoreverse effect like with Core Animation?

Answer (score 11):

Answer from Andrey Gordeev is close enough,

```
float x = car.position.x;
SKAction *a = [SKAction moveToX:(x+10) duration:0.5];
SKAction *b = [SKAction moveToX:x duration:0.5];
SKAction *seq = [SKAction sequence:@[a,b]];
[car runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:seq]];
```

moveToX:(x+10) will make it swing by 10 (instead of go at point X=10).

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for this answer a long time. This will help me with a lot of other stuff I'll need

Answer (score 1):

Add reverse action manually:

```
float x = car.position.x;
SKAction *a = [SKAction moveToX:10 duration:0.5];
SKAction *b = [SKAction moveToX:x duration:0.5];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[a,b]];
[car runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The **repeatActionForever**: method do reverse the action.

The problem is the **moveToX**: action that is not reversible

The Apple documentation for each action show if it is reversible or not.

PS: the **moveByX:y:duration:** action is reversible

Comment: Can you give an example how you would create an autoreversing, looping animation? SKAction *a = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:10 duration:2.5]; a = [SKAction repeatActionForever:a.reversedAction]; just keeps adding 10 forever. No reversing (up and down). I also tried SKAction *a = [SKAction moveByX:5 y:10 duration:2.5]; a = [SKAction repeatActionForever:a.reversedAction]; which only reverses the direction. But no autoreversing.